# Displaying a polygon in OpenLayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a polygon in (longitude, latitude) points I'd like to draw:

```
      var maxPoint = [36.283, -114.368];
      var geoSquare = [ minPoint, [minPoint[0], maxPoint[1]], maxPoint, [maxPoint[0], minPoint[1]]];
      var polygonFeature = new Feature(
              new Polygon(geoSquare));
```

I am drawing a map in the following way:

```
      var map = new Map({
        interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([new Drag()]),
        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new TileJSON({
              url: 'https://maps.siemens.com/styles/osm-bright.json'
            })
          }),
          new VectorLayer({
            source: new VectorSource({
              features: [polygonFeature]
            }),
            style: new Style({
              stroke: new Stroke({
                width: 3,
                color: [255, 0, 0, 1]
              }),
              fill: new Fill({
                color: [0, 0, 255, 0.6]
              })
            })
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
```

This Polygon is near Southern California, but I don't see the square on the map at all. What is wrong??

**EDIT**

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m71qjchd/7/)

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a fiddle.

Comment: @randomSoul edited to include jsfiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feature coordinates must be in LonLat format and must be transformed to the view projection.  A polygon ring must start and end at the same point and a polygon needs an extra pair of `[]` as they can have addition internal rings (holes). Alternative you can create a polygon from an extent.  Any of these would work.

```
  var minPoint = [-121.091, 32.92];
  var maxPoint = [-114.368, 36.283];
  var geoSquare = [[minPoint, [minPoint[0], maxPoint[1]], maxPoint, [maxPoint[0], minPoint[1]], minPoint]];
  var polygonFeature = new Feature(
    new Polygon(geoSquare).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'));



  var minPoint = [-121.091, 32.92];
  var maxPoint = [-114.368, 36.283];
  var polygonFeature = new Feature(
    Polygon.fromExtent(minPoint.concat(maxPoint)).transform('EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'));


  var minPoint = fromLonLat([-121.091, 32.92]);
  var maxPoint = fromLonLat([-114.368, 36.283]);
  var geoSquare = [[minPoint, [minPoint[0], maxPoint[1]], maxPoint, [maxPoint[0], minPoint[1]], minPoint]];
  var polygonFeature = new Feature(
    new Polygon(geoSquare));


  var minPoint = fromLonLat([-121.091, 32.92]);
  var maxPoint = fromLonLat([-114.368, 36.283]);
  var polygonFeature = new Feature(
    Polygon.fromExtent(minPoint.concat(maxPoint)));
```

Comment: This extra pair of [] for the Polygon coordinates can lead to a real frustration if you neglect it. Wasted a lot of time trying to figure out why the Polygon wouldn't show up on the map, whereas the same coordinates would work for a LineString. Thanks!